# Understanding compilation result for std::isnan

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, x86, ieee-754

I always assumed, that there is practically no difference between testing for `NAN` via

- `x!=x`

or

- `std::isnan(x)`

However, gcc provides different assemblers for both versions ([live on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/BBFM3Q)):

```
  ;x!=x:
  ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm0
  movl $1, %edx
  setne %al
  cmovp %edx, %eax
  ret

  ;std::isnan(x)
  ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm0
  setp %al
  ret
```

However, I'm struggling to understand both version. My naive try to compile `std::isnan(x)` would be:

```
  ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm0
  setne %al   ;return true when not equal
  ret
```

but I must be missing something.

Probably, there is missed optimization in the `x!=x`-version (Edit: it is probably a [regression in gcc-8.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86497)).

My question is, why is the parity flag ([`setp`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SETcc.html), `PF=1`)  and not the equal flag ([`setne`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SETcc.html), `ZF=0`) used in the second version?

Comment: Because the zero-flag isn't set to 0 https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_316.html

Comment: Clang emits the same code in both cases.

Comment: @HadiBrais it looks like a regression in gcc-8.1, I submitted a bug report https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86497

Comment: @ead: I can't edit your bug on bugzilla, but you should retitle it `[8/9 regression] wasted instructions for x86 float x!=x` and add the missed-optimization tag.  So the gcc devs know it's not a correctness problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `x!=x` is due to a [regression introduced to gcc-8](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86497), clang produces the same assembler for both versions.

My misunderstanding about the way [`ucomisd`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_316.html) is functioning was pointed out by @tkausl. The result of this operation can be:

```
        unordered       <       >       ==
ZF         1            0       0       1
PF         1            0       1       0
CF         1            1       0       0
```

In the case of `ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm` only the outcomes "unordered" and "==" are possible.

The case of `NaN` is unordered and for this ZF is set the same as in  the case of `==`. Thus we can use the flags `PF` and `CF` to differentiate between two possible outcomes.